# Почему не заменяется символ?

Tags: javascript

По заданию написал такое решение, почему у меня в коде все символы "a" в строке не заменяются на 4, где ошибка, что я делаю не так?
Я прошелся по дебагеру, но всё равно не понимаю!
Почему  "output[i] = input[i]" output показывает как undefined когда она определена var output = ''?

```
var input = 'javascript is awesome'
var output = ''
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  if (input[i] === 'a') {
    output[i] = '4'
  } else {
    output[i] = input[i]
  }
  output += output[i]
}
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Предлагаю вам воспользоваться отладкой. В будущем будете очень часто использовать. И перестанете гадать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ты действительно считаешь что твой ответ поясняет почему в JS строки не ведут себя как в C++ ? Было-бы хорошо с твоей стороны не закрывать вопросы с кликбейтом, а полноценно ответить на вопрос!!!

Comment: @EugeneX все вопросы к разработчикам SO, почему нет выбора предложить дубликат без одновременного закрытия вопроса для золотых медалистов ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯    Попросить модера переоткрыть вопрос и перенести ссылку из закрывашки в комментарий - пользуйтесь....... А дебажить код вполне себе поможет понять на каком этапе что происходит с каждой переменной и что с этим делать, да.